# Java doing Math not as expected

Tags: java, math, rounding-error

I have this really weird problem with Java. Basicly, this is what is going on:

```
 int i = (int) Math.ceil((30 * 50) / 1000);
```

which would be the same as

```
 int i = (int) Math.ceil(1.5);
```

but it doesn't return 2, it returns 1! However, the seccond line does return 2! This is really weird...

If it helps, here's the actual line of code:

```
            pStats.setPlayerEnergy(
                player,
                pStats.getPlayerEnergy(player)
                        + (int) Math.ceil((pStats.getPlayerFoodTick(player) * pStats
                                .getPlayerHydrationTick(player)) / 1000));
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Look at the types of *all the expressions* within `(30 * 50) / 1000`. What kind of arithmetic do you think will happen with those expressions? (This question isn't really about `Math.ceil...` Print out the value of the expression inside, and see what you get...)

Comment: Dividing integer by integer yields integer? What's so strange about it?

Comment: @MightyPork It is not that obvious, it is merely a convention - another possible convention would be to return a double when the result of the division is not exact. That is what most spreadhseets do for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

integer/integer will give you the integer value make any value either denominator or numerator as float you will get the answer

```
int i = (int) Math.ceil((30 * 50) / 1000.0);

                or

int i = (int) Math.ceil((30.0 * 50) / 1000);

                or 

int i = (int) Math.ceil((30 * 50.0) / 1000);
```

Comment: @ionree have you got this my friend

Comment: Yeah, I converted one of the values to float and it worked. But I have to wait another 4 minutes to accept an answer

Comment: Just accepted it. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 4):

This is Integer division. In Java:

(30 * 50) / 1000 = 1

```
int i = (int) Math.ceil((30.0 * 50) / 1000);
```

Will give you the expected result.

Comment: Add some more explanation

Comment: So basicly, i would simply have to convert the getPlayerFoodTick to float, and it should work? Java has some serious issues sometimes...

**EDIT:** tried it, it works now